# How to determine the average number of notes per user?

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I have the following two tables in my MySQL database:

```
User (id, created_at, ...)
Note (id, created_at, ...)
```

What I'm hoping to do with my DB is generate a report like so:

```
Users created X weeks ago | X of users | average number of notes
1 | 20 | 2
2 | 31 | 3
3 |  5 | 4
```

Last row example... 3 weeks ago, 5 users were created in just that week range, and they on average have created a total of 4 notes.

Where the users selected per row is based on that week range... and the average number of notes is for the user during any time frame...

Can this be done with SQL or is this to complex and I'll need to build this into my Rails app?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What version of MySQL? 8.0 or 5.x?

Comment: @TheImpaler MariaDB 10.2

Comment: Fixed the tag to "mariadb".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
select floor(datediff(u.created_at, curdate()) / 7) as weeks_ago,
       count(distinct u.id) as numusers, 
       count(n.id) / count(distinct u.id) as avg_notes
from users u left join
     notes n
     on u.id = n.id
group by weeks_ago;
```

The main caveat in this query is how you define "weeks ago".  This simply takes the number of days and divides by 7.

Comment: hmm, that does not seem to be outputting data the works... I had to update it as created_at was ambiguous and the DB errord, perhaps I updated it incorrectly.

Comment: @AnnaSm . . . All the columns should be qualified.  My bad.

Comment: actually false alarm, avg_notes is always 1.0000

Comment: should it be n.user_id and not n.id?

Comment: Why is weeks_ago, outputting like: "-23.1429"and "-23.0000" "-22.8571" "-22.7143"

Comment: @AnnaSm . . . Because I forgot the `floor()`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 : - A single query

It can be done in MySql but you might need to think of performance of the query if not properly built and indexed

Solution2 : Multiple queries (Algo below)

Loop for each week 
1) query 1 - Get all userids created in that week. [Interval](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) in MySql might be useful.  
2) Use these userids to get number of notes based on userd id and created_at

Comment: algo below? what does that mean? ty